# Как сделать один обработчик onСlick для разных Button

Tags: java

Есть 2 элемента `View` и 2 элемента `Button`. Хочу, чтобы по клику по одному `Button` текст менялся лишь в одном `View`, а не в двух, как это происходит сейчас.

Не знаю как в коде разделить это все.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private TextView m2TextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        m2TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        mTextView.setText("privet ot  1 view");
        m2TextView.setText("Privet ot 2 view");

    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дали правильный ответ - проголосуйте за него\отметьте его верным ( серая галочка сбоку ответа). Это поможет другим понять, что ответ подошел для решения проблемы. Писать в комментарии - "спасибо,работает" не следует.

Answer (score 3):

Перепишите ваш обрабочик следующим образом:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.btn1:
        mTextView.setText("privet ot  1 view");
        break;

    case R.id.btn2:
        m2TextView.setText("Privet ot 2 view");
        break;
    }
}
```

Только `R.id.btn1` и `R.id.btn2` заменит на `id` своих кнопок

Comment: Спасибо большое. всё работает.